# Как читать файл в C++ построчно?

Tags: c++, файлы

Нужно, чтобы программа читала только определенные строки в файле, например, 1 строку или 7, но не весь файл целиком

Answer (score 2):

Только если строки фиксированной длины, тогда читаете как обычный файл случайного доступа. Если строки переменной длины (то есть позиции строк неизвестны), единственный способ это читать все, откидывая ненужное.

Answer (score 2):

Так сделать невозможно, файл всё равно будет читаться последовательно. Можно читать построчно, и останавливаться для анализа только на строках нужного номера, например так:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("my_file.txt")
    std::string line;
    int num = 0;
    while (std::getline(fin, line))
    {
        ++num;
        if (num == 1 || num == 7)
        {
            doSomething(line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Первую строку печатает, при изменении числа строки - нет вывода

Comment: http://cpp.sh/6cx5p - всё работает, печатает все строки. Скорее всего он напечатал у вас первую и седьмую строки, а седьмой не было, вот и показалось, будто он читает только первую. (чтобы сделать ввод - снизу там поставьте Standart Input -> Text, и напишите в окошке ниже несколько строчек)